# Newbie: Ubuntu One: struggling with the Sync

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, ubuntu-one-windows

This is my first attempt at using a Linux based OS.

I signed up using Ubuntu One, I then logged into the Ubuntu One cloud site. I created a folder, I uploaded some personal varsity documents into a folder. I run the Ubuntu One app, but I have no idea how to have the folder created shown up.

I have included a picture of what I did, and hope to achieve.

[image]

Comment: are you using the windows client? Your screenshot shows what looks like a windows 7 task bar across the bottom...

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots it is, and it's irrelevant to the question if Windows or Ubuntu is being used.

Comment: it's relevant because that's a separate (but still supported) piece of software that may have its own bugs and peculiarities. :)

Answer (score 2):

The folder you created on the web site is not a special folder that is synchronized separately. If you open your home folder (profile directory on Windows), the folder you're looking for should be underneath the `Ubuntu One` folder, within that directory.

Also, you should *stop* synchronization of the `.local/share/ubuntuone/shares` folder. It is a special folder that contains all the folders which have been shared to you by other users, so synchronizing it will duplicate all those files into your own account's storage, and take up your available storage quota. It will also waste your bandwidth by downloading everything and then duplicating things once they've downloaded.